# experimental make_array, can I use brace-init list as arguments?

Tags: c++, arrays, variadic-templates, c++17

I tried to implement a version of make_array that is not exactly the same, but very similar to:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/make_array

I found that this code seems not to work, am I right about this?

```
using MyType = std::pair<int, float>;

constexpr auto the_array = make_array<MyType>({1, 7.5f});
```

The problem here seems to be that, even if `make_array` specifies explicitly the first template parameter, the arguments still come from a  parameter pack,
which is unrelated to the explicitly specified argument.

This means that the code will not work.

Is there any solution that can make the code above work?

My version

```
template <class Val = void, class... Args,
      class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_void<Val>{}, int>>
constexpr std::array<
std::tuple_element_t
<0,
 std::tuple<Args...>>,
sizeof...(Args)> makeArray(Args &&... args) {
    return {{std::forward<Args>(args)...}};
}

template <class Val = void, class... Args,
      class = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_void<Val>{}, int>>
constexpr std::array<
    Val,
    sizeof...(Args)> makeArray(Args &&... args) {
    return {{std::forward<Val>(args)...}};
}
```

Comment: Are you getting compiler or runtime errors?

Comment: Compile-time, but I think that I found the solution, (maybe), inside make_array I just return a {{std::forward<Val>(args)...}} instead of {{std::forward<Args>(args)...}}. Would that work?

Comment: Don't know. There's no `Val` template param in the cppreference possible implementation.

Comment: How about you show us your version of `make_array`?

Comment: @SimonKraemer here you are. Above edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`make_array` is a variadic template function which takes arguments of any type. It will then perform implicit conversion on these parameters to get to the array's base type. As such, unless you specify every argument's type, the compiler will have to use template argument deduction.

And braced-init-lists cannot be deduced (outside of `auto` variables). So you will have to explicitly mention the type name when constructing each member.

Comment: @GermánDiago: No. Because that would then turn it into an `initializer_list`. And `make_array` doesn't create arrays from `initializer_list`s.

Comment: Actually what I mean is: could I try something like template <class Val> makeArray(std::initilizer_list<Val>) and use it as makeArray<MyType>({{5, 7.5}, ...}}) I just want to get rid of the explicit MyType for all elements in the array.

Comment: @GermánDiago: I know what you meant, and it still won't work. You can't use the size of an `initializer_list` in the template argument list of `std::array`. Not through a function at any rate.

Comment: @GermánDiago for a work-around, you could create a type `Ctors<T>` that has synthesized constructors that accept `N`, `N-1`, `N-2`, ..., `0` arguments of type `T` (for some fixed upper limit, say 10) and make `make_array<T>` have a `Ctors<T>` parameter. Then `make_arrray<MyType>({{ a, b }})` should work and create the `array<MyType, 1>` object.